# how to apply css property at runtime?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

i have html code

```
 <div id="div1"></div>
```

I am loading content onto it dynamically and setting its width in "success" function based on the contents

heres jquery code

data is an array returned by php and data.length=30;

```
 success: function (data) {
        var data1=data;
        var w2=(data1.length)*100;
        $("#div1").css({'width':w2+'px'});
        alert($("#div").width();
```

but when i alert it I am getting NULL value and div1 is set a default width

Comment: data1.length has value?

Comment: Try to check your values using a JavaScript debugger (Chrome inspection tools, for example) to check that the `w2` variable has the value you expect. Other than that, your code is right.

Comment: @RaraituL..ya..when i i aler just w1 value i am getting expected value

Comment: @user1814087 For easier debugging javascript objects, use Firebug extension from Firefox. It makes your work much easier

Answer (score 0):

you applied the css to selector different with the selector used in alert and alert is miss )

```
 $("#div1").css('width',w2+'px');
alert($("#div").width());
```

Comment: How is that different than the above (despite the obvious syntactical difference)

Comment: the css() function take two parameters : the css property and css value

Comment: It can be used both ways so your example is exactly the same as the question

Answer (score 0):

Set it like so

```
      $("#div1").css('width', w2);
```

And then alert width of "#div1" and not "#div".. like so

```
      alert($("#div1").width());
```

So the full thing:

```
success: function (data) {
    var data1=data;
    var w2=(data1.length)*100;
    $("#div1").css('width', w2);
    alert($("#div1").width());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you function, I also removed data1, because it wasn't useful
and make the code a little more readable

```
function (data) {
    var w2 = data.length * 100;
    $("#div1").css('width', w2);
    alert($("#div").width());
}
```